# Updating Single Row per Group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**The Background**

I have a temporary table containing information including a unique rowID, OrderNumber, and guestCount.  RowID and OrderNumber already exist in this table, and I am running a new query to fill in the missing guestCount for each orderNumber.  I would like to then update the temp table with this information.

**Example**

What I currently have looks something like this, with only RowID being unique, meaning that there can be multiple items having the same OrderNumber.

```
    RowID | OrderNumber | guestCount
    1     | 30001       | 0
    2     | 30002       | 0
    3     | 30002       | 0
    4     | 30003       | 0
```

My query returns the following table, only returning one total number of guests per orderNumber:

```
    OrderNumber | guestCount
    30001       | 3
    30002       | 10
    30003       | 5
```

The final table should look like:

```
    RowID | OrderNumber | guestCount
    1     | 30001       | 3
    2     | 30002       | 10
    3     | 30002       | 0
    4     | 30003       | 5
```

I'm only interested in updating one (doesn't matter which) entry per orderNumber, but my current logic is resulting in errors:

```
UPDATE temp
SET temp.guestCount = cc.guestCount
FROM( SELECT OrderNumber, guestCount
      FROM (SELECT OrderNumber, guestCount, RowID = MIN(RowID)
      FROM #tempTable
      GROUP BY RowID, OrderNumber, guestCount) t)temp
INNER JOIN queryTable q ON temp.OrderNumber = q.OrderNumber
```

I'm not sure if this logic is even a valid way of doing this, but I do know that I'm getting errors in my update due to the fact that I'm using an aggregate function, as well as a GROUP function.  Is there any way to go about this operation differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the row to update by using `row_number()` in a CTE.  This identifies the first row in the group for the update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by OrderNumber order by id) as seqnum
      from #tempTable tt
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET toupdate.guestCount = q.guestCount
    FROM toupdate
    INNER JOIN queryTable q
    ON temp.OrderNumber = q.OrderNumber
    where toupdate.seqnum = 1;
```

The problem with you query is that `temp` is based on an aggregation subquery.  Such a subquery is not updatable, because it does not have a 1-1 relationship with the rows of the original query.  Using the CTE with `row_number()` is updatable.  In addition, your `set` statement uses the table alias `cc` which is not defined in the query.

Comment: Does this method actually update the rows in the original 'temp' table, or does it create a completely separate table (CTE?) holding only the selected rows?  If I were to then call a select statement on the temp table after performing this action, would it return the updated results, or are they only stored for the CTE?

Comment: For future reference:  Yes, it does return the updated results.  Nifty!  +1 for you!

Comment: @TaylorBigham . . . You can learn about updatable views in the SQL Server documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).  This applies to CTEs as well.